# Java singleton with init method

Tags: java, design-patterns, initialization, singleton

Singleton is a service that require injection of authentication and configuration data. I end with class:

```
class SingleService {
    private String conn;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    private SingleService() {
        // Can throw exception!!
        conn = Config.getProperty("conn");
        user = Config.getProperty("user");
        pass = Config.getProperty("pass");
        // Can throw exception!!
        internalService = tryConnect(conn, user, pass);
    }

    private static SingleService instance;

    public static void init() {
        instance = new SingleService();
    }

    public static synchronized SingleService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) init();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Dedicated `init()` method used for exception handling during application startup to early detect initialization errors early because later we just call `getInstance()` and doesn't expect to get errors:

```
class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
             Config.init("classpath:auth.properties");
             SingleService.init();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Can't init SingleService...");
            System.exit()
        }
        doJob();
    }
    private static void doJob() {
        SingleService.getInstance().doJob();
    }
}
```

I worry about `init()` method and singleton class signature. Fill that class was designed badly but don't understand what's wrong.

Is it possible to move away initialization from `getSingleton()` and `synchronized` and preserving control on exception during initialization?

Comment: (1) Singleton is an anti-pattern, and it is usually causing more pain than benefit. (2) Your last sentence (which seems to be the question) `It is good move away initialisation from getSingleton and synchronized but I don't figure how...` is unclear

Comment: I rework question for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My production code for problem I have sought:

```
public abstract class AbstractCaller<Port> {

    abstract protected Port createPort();

    protected init() {
        Port port = createPort();
        // heavy use of introspection/reflection on **port** object.
        // Results are used later by **call** method.
    }

    public call() {
        // Reflection based on data collected by **init** method.
    }
}

public class ConcreteCaller extends AbstractCaller<ConcretePort> {

    private ConcreteService service = new ConcreteService();

    @Override
    protected ConcretePort createPort() {
        return service.getPort();
    }

    private static class Holder {
        public static ConcreteCaller INSTANCE;
        static {
            INSTANCE = new ConcreteCaller();
            INSTANCE.init();
        }
    }

    public static Caller getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Abstract class has common `init` method that can only operate on fully initialized concrete class. Inner static class is used for lazy instantiation and perform `init` invocation.

There is no way to apply `init` method from superclass constructor to avoid need to call `init` in each implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would code it so you can throw exceptions if needed but still have a thread safe singleton.

```
enum SingleService {
    INSTANCE;

    private String conn;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private SingleService instance;

    public synchronized void init(Config config) throws SomeException {
        // don't leave in a half state if we fail.
        internalService = null; 

        conn = config.getProperty("conn");
        user = config.getProperty("user");
        pass = config.getProperty("pass");
        internalService = tryConnect(conn, user, pass);
    }

    public synchronized void methodForService() {
        if (internalService == null) throw new IllegalSateException();
        // do work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SingleService ss1 = SingleService.getInstance();
SingleService.init();
SingleService ss2 = SingleService.getInstance();
```

So `ss1` is a different object than `ss2` which is not what Singleton is designed for. If `ss1` is modified at anytime `ss2` will remain unaffected.

Comment: Ok, now I become understand what wrong with `init()` method, thanks!

Comment: Still interesting  how to detect initialisation issue on application startup. Seems that fake `getInstance()` in `main()` solve issue.  I must delete `init()` or make it `private`.

Comment: Maybe you could make the method `getInstance` to return null if any problem arise while initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all you souhld not expose object creation method. If you want to check something, than go with asserts or any operation that will not corrupt instance object.

```
public static void checkIfValid() {
   assert Config.getProperty("conn");// do not corrupt instance object
   assert Config.getProperty("user");
   assert Config.getProperty("pass");
}

public static synchronized SingleService getInstance() {
    if (instance == null){ // only here you can initiate instance object
       instance = new SingleService();
    }
    return instance;
}
```